# How to check if variable is empty in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-5

I have this code in my view file:

```
                        @if(!empty($slug))
                            dd(11);
                        <a href="{{$post->url}}" class="latest-heading">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}..</a>

                        @else
                        dd(22);
                        <a href="{{$post->slug}}" class="latest-heading">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}..</a>
                        @endif
```

I have one post that has data in the slug database table column.  The other posts do not.  They have data only in the url column.  But at the moment, I am seeing dd(22) next to each post.  The post with data in the slug column has the slug in its URL structure.  The other posts do not have anything their URLs.  Their URL is website.com/articles

Any ideas?

This is the code in my routes file, by the way:

```
 Route::get('articles/{url}', 'postsController@viewpost');
```

Not sure how to edit it to put articles/{slug}

Posts controller:

```
 public function viewpost($url,$slug){
  if ( empty($slug) ) {
  $url ='articles/'.$url;
  }  else {
  $url = 'articles/'.$slug;

}

  $posts = posts::where('post_status', '')->get();
  if ( empty($slug) ) {
  $post = $posts->where('url', $url)->first();
  }  else {
  $post = $posts->where('slug', $slug)->first();
}

  if ( empty($post) )
return redirect()->back();


return view('viewpost')->with('post', $post)->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

Recent posts code:

```
<h3>Recent Posts</h3>
@foreach($posts as $post)
     <p><a href="{{ URL::to($post->url) }}"><img style="width:100px;" src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$post->thumbnail)}}" class="responsive"></a><br>
         <a href="{{ URL::to($post->url) }}">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}..</a></p>               
@endforeach
```

Comment: Show your postsController as well

Comment: post updated @MasoudHaghbin

Comment: can you give me an example of slug and url content ?

Comment: only difference is slug is shorter.  only one post has data in the slug column because the url was so long.  I wanted it to have a short url so I created a slug for it.  so example....url: bananas-are-found-in-asia.  slug: bananas-asia

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code

```
Route::get('articles/{url}', 'postsController@viewpost');
```

only sends $url to the Controller function so $slug is always empty.
Also you are sending $post and $posts variables to your view so $slugs is always empty there too . that's why its always in else showing dd(22)

Comment: I already have that in my routes file... Also, the URLs in the posts that do not use slugs are not displaying properly.  They are displaying as website.com/articles without the rest of the URL.

Comment: you are printing in reverse ! when slug is empty you are printing slug again not url

Comment: ok and now they are all showing dd(11) except now the post with the slug is not showing its slug data correctly.  All the other posts are showing their proper URLs.  Also, when I click on a post, I get a Missing argument 2 error in the controller file in the if else code.

Comment: I dont see any foreach in your code and also could you show me how you modified your blade!?

Comment: I'm not angry :)))) , I posted another answer which I think will fix all of the issues

Answer (score 0):

My other answer was Why you are always seeing dd(22).
for correcting the issue :

```
public function viewpost($url){
  $posts = posts::where('post_status', '');
  $post = $posts->where('url', $url)->orWhere('slug' , $url)->first();
}

  if ( empty($post) )
return redirect()->back();


return view('viewpost')->with('post', $post)->with('posts', $posts->get());
}
```

and your blade :

```
@if(!empty($post->slug))
                            dd(11);
                        <a href="{{'articles/'.$post->slug}}" class="latest-heading">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}..</a>

                        @else
                        dd(22);
                        <a href="{{'articles/'.$post->url}}" class="latest-heading">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}..</a>
                        @endif
```

Comment: error in the controller file: Method orWhere does not exist.

Comment: I changed it :)

Comment: 2 problems: 1) the Recent Posts function in my view file no longer shows posts (will post the code up). 2) the posts with no slug do not work.  when I click on the post, it redirects to /articles.